# Is the R package AWR.Athena, vulnerable to the security issue in log4j?

Tags: r, log4j, rjava, rjdbc

AWR.Athena package as per CRAN imports RJDBC, rJava. Hence suspecting if it is vulnerable to the recent Apache Log4j security issue. So information on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.